# How to refer to functional interface instance inside lambda in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to refer to functional interface instance inside lambda in Koltin.

Here is the example code:

```kotlin
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: androidx.lifecycle.Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {value ->
        observer.onChanged(value)
        removeObserver(this)
    } )
}
```

in the code above the compiler doesn't recognize this, how can I refer to `Observer` instance?

I tried to label `Observer` like this:

```
Observer here@ {

}
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems not possible. If we use a full `object : Observer {}` syntax, then IntelliJ suggests to replace it with a lambda. However, as soon as we use `this` anywhere inside its function, it stops suggesting the fix. It seems IDE "knows" it is not possible to reference `this` from a lambda. But I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is not possible. Lambdas cannot reference their own instances in Kotlin. However, object expressions can. That means you can do the following:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {
            observer.onChanged(value)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```

If you need to reference the observer instance many times throughout your code, and you prefer to be able to use lambda syntax, then you can create an alternative `observe` method like so:

```kotlin
// function could probably use a better name
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeAlt(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>.(T) -> Unit) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {
            this.observer(value)
        }
    })
}
```

And then you can change your `observeOnce` implementation like so:

```kotlin
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner, LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observeAlt(lifecycleOwner) { value ->
        observer.onChanged(value)
        removeObserver(this@observeAlt) // label not necessary, but aids readability
    }
}
```

Of course, this essentially wraps the `Observer` in a higher-order function, and you still can't reference said higher-order function itself.